# How can i reduce the time complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can I reduce the complexity of an algorithm? I'm currently doing hackerrank, where I made a solution for climbing the leaderboard, but two tests are failing because of the time limit.

I'm trying to learn how to refactor my code, with less time complexity, but I have no idea how I could reduce the two for loops into one, because I have to iterate through both of the arrays to check if the player score is higher or equal to the ranked leaderboard.

The description of the task: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/

I could search a solution for this, but I want to learn how can I reduce time complexity in codes that I write, what my thinking should look like when I try to do this?

```
function climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player) {
    let positions = [];
    let temp = new Set(...[ranked]);
    ranked = Array.from(temp);
    for(let i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < ranked.length; j++) {
            if(player[i] > ranked[j] || player[i] === ranked[j]) {
                positions.push(j+1);
                break;
            } else if(j === ranked.length-1) {
                positions.push(j+2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Comment: Mostly you can't just refactor code to reduce time complexity. An analogy is that this is like asking "how do I refactor a bicycle into a ferrari" -- what you have and what you need are often completely different (because they use different designs, even if they have some things in common). You have to learn and practice algorithmic approaches and figure out a suitable application of them for a particular problem that you're given.

Comment: For this problem, you need to think about what you need to precompute (in O(n) time) and what state you need to remember between games so that you can figure out the player's new position in the leaderboard given the next score in amortized O(1) time. It seems reasonable to expect O(n) behavior overall, and that's actually the final time complexity when you solve it.

Comment: @PaulHankin: the complexity will also depend on m.

Comment: Hints: you need a data structure that holds the scores in decreasing order, with efficient insertions. In case of ties, there is no need to keep several instances of the score.

Comment: You cannot change the complexity of an algorithm. You'd need a different algorithm to achieve a different complexity.

Comment: You should post the requirement in the post, not link.

Comment: I don't see the reason of `...[ranked]` btw (which is basically `ranked`)

Comment: *"I want to learn how can i reduce time complexity"*: that requires experience. *"what my thinking should look like"*: that is the intuition you form by lots of practice. *"I could search a solution for this"*: so then we should not provide it here either, as that would be just the same thing. All the rest (how to become a good algorithm finder) is a matter of opinion, and is out of scope on this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would be more suited on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.